# How to reset the id of pm2?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I using pm2. After I started my app several times, the id increased. I deleted all in pm2, and started again, but the id didn't count from 0 any more. How can I reset it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution is to restart pm2, by typing `pm2 kill` as said by ItalyPaleAle in the comments.

Answer (score 11):

Looking at the help menu (`pm2 --help`) it seems like `pm2 reset` would be the way to go. But that command resets metadata (restarted time, etc) and does not reset IDs. One solution is to use `pm2 kill` to kill the pm2 daemon and restart it again (thanks, @Yao Zhao). But doing so will stop all current processes. A better approach would be to save the list of current processes, restart pm2, and then restore those processes using the following set of commands.

```bash
$ pm2 save      # save current processes
$ pm2 kill      # kill pm2 daemon
$ pm2 resurrect # load saved processes
```

Comment: I need to clean up the process id list (due to recent additional apps). This is exactly what I need. All process ID list now in sequence. It was not before due to issues getting the new app up to work. Great! Thank!

Answer (score 4):

Per pm2's GitHub:

```
$ pm2 reset <process>    # Reset meta data (restarted time...)
```

Reference: [GitHub issue#1456](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/1546)

Comment: The Question is about resetting the "id" counter, not the metadata of a process.